# How to avoid image copyright infringement

Tags: copyright, canada

I am making a website for a client who has a store and is trying to sell their products on the web now. I told the client that they would need to provide me with images of all of their products and instead, they directed me to the websites that sell the same items and told me to use their images instead.

I explained that we would need to at least provide a shoutout to the website for using their images but the client does not want this.

Do I need to be worried about using another web site's images when I am simply the builder of the web site who is not gaining any personal benefit besides being able to use the web site as part of my portfolio?

Comment: Where are you -- i.e. which jurisdiction does this relate to?

Comment: i am in Canada, as an update to this question: the client told me that she has permission from the Website to use their images. Should I still be worried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the abstract, two businesses that cooperate in violating a third party's copyright could both face liability. Applying that information to the facts you gave would amount to legal counsel. If you don't want to tell the client 'no,' you should speak to a lawyer about your potential liability.

Beyond the legalities, do you really want your portfolio to advertise that you design sites by ripping other sites off?